flash of unstyled content in react website with chakra
I am working on this bug for couple of hours and I was not able to find any solution yet. In this react project I am using chakra. When making the it responsive I am using the useBreakpointValue({ base: false, lg: true }); but before return the value it seems to be render the webpage. After if returns it value website is re-render with new values. This seems to be the problem. I tried to solve but I failed. Could anyone help with this.
import { Box, Flex, Image, Stack, Text, useBreakpointValue, Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import { LoginForm } from "./login_form";
import { colors } from "theme/colors";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouterPaths } from "router/routerConfig";

const Login: React.FC = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleLogin = () => {
  console.log('Login clicked');
  navigate(RouterPaths.REGISTER); // Navigate to the next page after login
};

const isLargeScreen = useBreakpointValue({ base: false, lg: true });
const effectiveIsLargeScreen = typeof isLargeScreen === 'undefined' ? true : isLargeScreen;

return (
  <Flex direction="column" h="100vh">
    {!isLargeScreen && (
      <Flex direction="row" bg={colors.primary[500]} p="5">
        <Heading m="auto" color="white">Drop Here</Heading>
      </Flex>
    )}

    <Flex direction="row" >
      {isLargeScreen && (
        <Box w="50%" bg={colors.primary[500]} >
          <Stack direction="column" p="50" h="100vh" spacing={4}>
            <Flex alignItems="center">
              <Image src="/images/White_T.png" w={"14"} />
              <Text fontSize="30px" fontWeight="800" color="white" ml={-2}>Drop Here</Text>
            </Flex>

            <Text fontSize="40px" fontWeight="600" color="white" pt="20%" lineHeight="shorter">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            </Text>

            <Text minW={400} color="white">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            </Text>

            <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" justifyContent="flex-end" height="100vh">
              <Text fontWeight={300} color="white">© {new Date().getFullYear()} Drop Here. All rights reserved</Text>
            </Box>
          </Stack>
        </Box>
      )}
      <LoginForm onLogin={handleLogin} />
    </Flex>
  </Flex>
);
};

export default Login;


According to the docs:

Make sure to provide a base value when using useBreakpointValue so it doesn't return undefined in the first render.

try setting a base value on your code:
const isLargeScreen = useBreakpointValue({ base: 'lg', lg: true });

disclaimer: never used this module before. Answer only based on the available documentation.

With this that flash is gone. But now the website is not responsive

quick suggestion: put back the false value on base. log the final output of the function (with console.log(isLargeScreen)). then use that result as the base value, so you can have a sane default that works for you.

Something that is commonly missed is the { ssr: false } option. From the docs -

